# How to create a formula field which multiplies another formula field with a percent field?

Tags: formula, formula-field

**Please help, I need to create a new formula field which should be the multiplication of a formula field by a percent field.**

Formula field name is margin% - **(Total_T_Price__c - Total_N_ Price__c ) / Total_Net_Price__c**

Percent field name - Offerpercent

For both the above fields, the return type is percent and same for the new formula field.
So I'm creating a new formula field  as follows - **margin% * offerpercent**

But the new formula field is displaying as 0.00% even though there are values in the two fields being multiplied.

Comment: Did you try (temporarily) increasing the number of digits on the new field? That way you could check if there's anything being calculated behind the 2nd decimal. You might need to multiply both percentages with 100 before multiplying them.

Comment: @GuyClairbois Thanks for your valuable time, I've tried multiplying both values with 100 but still not working.

Comment: what if you put 1 single value in the new formula field? Either margin% or offerpercent. And see if any of those is 0.

Comment: tried that if I put any single value, it shows that value in the formula field but when I try to multiply the formula field and % field then it's not showing any value.

Comment: @GuyClairbois One of the fields offerpercent is showing values as 0 even tho it has 7.20 value

Comment: Very strange. Could you post a screenshot of the actual data? And possible also of the field definitions.

Answer (score -1):

According to me as formula field get calculated at the record load so it is causing issue.

What you can try is instead of referencing formula field in another formula field you can write both the formula again in third field.

For ex - Field A -> a1xb1
Field B --> c1xd1

**You are doing Field C --> Field AxField B instead of this try a1xb1xc1xd1**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @prajjwalagarwal Could you please elaborate a bit more, I'm not able to understand, maybe if you can please explain using the fields I have provided in the question? Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Formula for 3rd field will be -->( (Total_T_Price__c - Total_N_ Price__c ) / Total_Net_Price__c ) x offerpercent

Not margin x offerpercent

Comment: formula fields can have dependencies on each other. That should not be a problem.

Comment: @prajjwal agarwal I tried that before, but it's not working.

Comment: What is value of field margin% and offer % and what is type of 3rd field?

Comment: return type of both the fields that have to be multiplied is percent

Comment: I tried the way you are doing, I am getting values in 3rd field. Probably there is one of the field with value as 0

Comment: Margin % is 62.11 and offerpercent is 7.20. no field has 0 value

Comment: @prajjwalagrawal I tried putting only the offerpercent field in the new formula field but it's showing 0.00%, maybe that's the issue. don't know why that's happening.

Comment: Make sure you are not referencing other field with the same name. Check the api name and label again.

Comment: I tried creating new percentage fields and referred that in the formula field and still it's showing 0.00%, I don't know why it's happening